# webView2_PreviewKeyDown method of combination key not work in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

i have winform project(.NET 6). webview2 in tab 3 of tabcontrol ,webView2_PreviewKeyDown method of combination key Alt and M to trigger selected tab 1 not work. how can i do it?

```
   private void webView2_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.M)
            {
                //   tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[0];
                tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Override the `ProcessCmdKey` method of your Form instead

Comment: Hi,@Jimi. thanks. It seems that the  keydown and previouskeydown events are not firing in winform webview2 . Why?